# Error installing the Google App Engine Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to install the Google App Engine Eclipse plugin and I am getting some weird errors. I am on Mac OS X 10.10.3, using Eclipse 4.4 Luna (the J2EE edition).

When installing the said plugin, I am getting the errors from below. Any idea what might be wrong?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wb.core.lib,1.7.0.r44x201405021445.
File has invalid content:/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar
Invalid content:lib/nebula-cwt.jar
The file "lib/nebula-cwt.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
The file "lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar
The file "lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/nebula-cdatetime.jar
The file "lib/nebula-cdatetime.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
The file "lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
The file "lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/asm-all-3.3.1.jar
The file "lib/asm-all-3.3.1.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/MVEL-fork.jar
The file "lib/MVEL-fork.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar
The file "lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
The file "lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/guava-13.0.1.jar
The file "lib/guava-13.0.1.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Invalid content:lib/commons-primitives-1.0.jar
The file "lib/commons-primitives-1.0.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile1759626140156902181.jar" has been tampered!
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wb.runtime.lib,1.7.0.r44x201405021445.
File has invalid content:/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile2638864348494436902.jar
Invalid content:lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
The file "lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar" in the jar "/var/folders/k_/85g34xb57j94_hn61f0zy1500000gn/T/signatureFile2638864348494436902.jar" has been tampered!
```

Answer (score 1):

I've re-downloaded Eclipse, used a fresh workspace and now it magically worked.